# Close method is undefined for JavaSparkContext

Tags: java, apache-spark, undefined

I am writing a secondary sort class for spark in Java.  The book whos code I am following, has me instantiating a JavaSparkContext

```
final JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext();
```

At the end of the class, I close the Java Spark Context, using the .close(); method, which is in the Java Spark Context API, but I am receiving this error.

```
The method close() is undefined for JavaSparkContext
```

I have the correct imports, import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;

Comment: Which version of Spark did you specify in your build file?

Comment: I don't think I ever did that.

Comment: OK, you brought Spark jar files into your classpath somehow for your IDE to see it. Otherwise, it would complain it doesn't even know what a `JavaSparkContext` is. So do you know what versions of Spark those jar files represent?

Comment: I am using the spark-core_2.10-1.0.0 jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done Spark with Java, but it looks like you are using an outdated jar file that predates Java 7's introduction of `AutoCloseable`.

I think the easiest thing for you to do is to use a build tool like Gradle or Maven to fetch your Spark dependencies instead. As the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html) suggests, tell your build tool to grab this version of Spark:

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-core_2.11
version = 2.1.0
```

Note that this uses Spark v.2.1.0 instead of the very old 1.0.0 you are using *and* that you need Scala 2.11 as well. You don't have to write your code in Scala, but it needs to be in the classpath.

Once you have updated things, you should be able to close your `JavaSparkContext` just fine. Please post another question if you have issues with setup.

Comment: I have scala in my class path.  

Am I not already using Spark v.2.1.0?  That is the jar library I have imported.

Comment: The "1.0.0" in `spark-core_2.10-1.0.0` is the Spark version, so I would say no. Not to mention that you need not only the jar itself but all its dependencies. Fetching those manually is cumbersome, and you will make a mistake. This is why build tools are so useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help Vidya. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sounds good. If this answer proves helpful, be sure to upvote it and accept it. With so many people new to Spark, and in many cases new to programming on the JVM altogether, questions like yours will help them.

Comment: Fantastic. Please upvote and accept for future users. Good luck on your project!